# how to unload managed c++ dll？

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli, managed-c++

A.dll is a native c++ dll, B.dll is a managed c++ dll. A.dll depends on B.dll, so when load A.dll, B.dll is loaded automatically, but after A.dll is unloaded, B.dll is still loaded. Only A.dll depends on B.dll, why B.dll can't be unloaded? How to unload the managed c++ dll? I'm using vs2010.

Thanks

Comment: I use ::FreeLibrary API to unload the managed C++ dll evidently, it can be unloaded, is there any risk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot unload a managed assembly once it is loaded by the CLR. The only way is to kill the AppDomain.

Comment: Darin  Dimmitrov is right. To unload an Assembly you have to create separate AppDomain that will be responsible for separation with the AppDomain containing entry point to you application (typically exe file). For more those AppDomain-s must exchange String or value types only as else your B Assembly eventually loads into both of your AppDomain-s and thus prevents you from unloading B.

Answer (score 0):

Using normal officially known approaches this is not possible without unloading `AppDomain` - at least for .net 4.8 framework.

Theoretically it's possible to load managed .dll as in ram, see following prototype:

https://github.com/tapika/dllloader

But even thus it's possible to release it from native side - most probably it will cause some headache to managed side.