# Destructor of static instance in second dll not being called

Tags: c++, c++-cli

**Situation**

External library (LibraryExternal) that I cannot change calls LoadLibrary on LibraryA. After it is succesfully loaded, it calls an exported function AExport which returns a pointer to ClassA, which is a static instance. Before AExport returns, it too loads a library via LoadLibrary, called LibraryB. After succesfull load, it calls an exported function BExport which in turn returns a pointer to a static instance ClassB.

**IMPORTANT**

LibraryA is a c++ dll compiled with vs2012 xp tools and LibraryB is a c++/cli dll also compiled with vs2012 xp tools.

All libraries share some other libraries which only define what ClassA and ClassB need to derive from, in order to make sense of the pointers returned by AExport and BExport. They are nothing more than stubs and do not matter in this question (Only pure virtual functions, no fields and nothing being done in ctor/dtor).

**Result**

When LibraryExternal gets unloaded via program exit, it calls FreeLibrary on LibraryA. This succesfully calls the destructor of ClassA which in turn frees the library LibraryB. But the destructor of ClassB is never run somehow.

**Desired Result**

Have ClassB destructor run

*ClassA.h*

```
#include <StubA.h>

class StubB;

class ClassA: public StubA
{
    public:
        ClassA();
        ~ClassA();

        bool Initialize();

        static ClassA &GetInstance()
        {
            static ClassA INSTANCE;

            return INSTANCE;
        }

    private:
        ClassA(ClassA const &);
        void operator=(ClassA const&);

        HMODULE wrapperModule;
        StubB *wrapperPlugin;
};
```

*ClassA.cpp*

```
#include "ClassA.h"

#include <Windows.h>

// typedef WrapperPlugin *(*WrapperPluginInitType) (); This is normally in shared library

static const wchar_t *WRAPPER_MODULE_NAME = L"LibraryB.dll";
static const char *WRAPPER_MODULE_INIT_FUNCTION_NAME = "BExport";

ClassA::ClassA() :
    wrapperModule(NULL),
    wrapperPlugin(NULL)
{

}

ClassA::~ClassA()
{
    if (this->wrapperModule != NULL)
    {
        FreeLibrary(this->wrapperModule);
    }
}

bool CSharpBridge::Initialize()
{
    this->wrapperModule = LoadLibraryW(WRAPPER_MODULE_NAME);
    if (this->wrapperModule == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    WrapperPluginInitType wrapperPluginInit = reinterpret_cast<WrapperPluginInitType>(GetProcAddress(this->wrapperModule, WRAPPER_MODULE_INIT_FUNCTION_NAME));
    if (wrapperPluginInit == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    this->wrapperPlugin = wrapperPluginInit();
    if (this->wrapperPlugin == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(ddlexport) StubA *AExport()
    {
        if (!ClassA::GetInstance().Initialize())
        {
            return NULL;
        }

        return &ClassA::GetInstance();
    }
}
```

*ClassB.h*

```
#include <StubB.h>

class ClassB : public StubB
{
    public:
        ClassB ();
        ~ClassB ();

        static ClassB &GetInstance()
        {
            static ClassB INSTANCE;

            return INSTANCE;
        }

    private:
        ClassB (ClassB const &);
        void operator=(ClassB const&);
};
```

*ClassB.cpp*

```
#include "ClassB.h"

#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

ClassB::ClassB()
{
    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Desktop\\test1.txt");
    myfile << "ClassB::ClassB\r\n";
    myfile.close();
}

ClassB::~ClassB()
{
    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Desktop\\test3.txt");
    myfile << "ClassB::~ClassB\r\n";
    myfile.close();
}

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) StubB *WrapperInit()
    {
        std::ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open("C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Desktop\\test2.txt");
        myfile << "WrapperInit\r\n";
        myfile.close();

        return &ClassB::GetInstance();
    }
}
```

Now I know with 100% certainty that ClassA ctor/dtor are called due to some LibraryExternal functions which give me some textual confirmation. And I do seem to be getting test1.txt and test2.txt generated. But NOT test3.txt.

After this I still need to create a managed reference to LibraryC which is a C# dll and 'destruct' that too when ClassB is being destructed.

Comment: At least comment to explain why you downvoted so I can do it better next time..

Comment: Hmm, I can see how that happened.  When you ask volunteers to invest their free time to help you then a minimum courtesy is to post code that they can compile and run to repro the problem.  This code does not compile and does not run.  Rather simple to take care of, just compile and run it yourself first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you cannot use FreeLibrary on a library that is managed from an unmanaged library. Since the managed library will start the AppDomain for which the unmanaged library knows nothing about. The AppDomain keeps the library alive and therefor the destructor was never ran. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697621/how-to-unload-managed-c-dll) answer.

Calling something from unmanaged to managed will still require some special attention since in not doing so will result in an exception: 0xC0020001: The string binding is invalid ! See [this](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/442784/best-gotchas-of-cplusplus-cli). What I did to fix the issue was having a static instance at ClassB scope and initializing it with the new operator in ClassB::GetInstance. Otherwise it would not be initialized at all. I then made a function ClassB::CleanUp in which I delete it. It is however important to mark the entire class (both header and source file) unmanaged with #pragma managed(push, off) and #pragma managed(pop).

To still be able to call managed methods/classes you have to make a function in the source file that has been surrounded with #pragma managed(push, on) and #pragma managed(pop). You can then call this function from the unmanaged class. This still seems strange to me, since that function is managed too?